# Auto-update ms-word graph based on a table in the same document

Tags: ms-word

Is there a way to link a table and a graph in ms-word? So that whenever I update the field in the table, the graph will automatically updated as well?

I google a bit about this but theres not much I can find.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

I can think of two possible approaches

1) Use the old MS Graph tool. Check in Insert/Text/Object, in the Create New tab whether "Microsoft Graph Chart" is available. If it's there, copy the table data, use this command to start up the tool. Select the sample data, then use Edit/Paste Link to paste in the data from the table. That will link the content.

2) Create a new Chart using the Insert/Illustrations/Chart tool (this starts up Excel). Copy the table information in Word and use Paste Special to paste it *with a link* into a Sheet in the Excel window. Back in Word, activate the Chart. In the Design tab select "Edit Data". Select the pasted Word data as the Range providing the chart data instead of the sample data.